# ReflectionException Class UsersTableSeeder does not exist , while i use composer dump-autoload still same error?

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{ 
    public function run()
    {
        User::create([
        'name'=> 'prakash',
        'username' => 'prakash',
        'number' => '*******',
        'active' => '1',
        'email'=> 'rock****@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('pokhrel215'),
        'remember_token'=> str_random(10),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried lots of time, but still same error what can I do?
I am a beginner at laravel.

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: [ReflectionException] Class UsersTableSeeder does not exist

Comment: did you add this in the run() of the DatabaseSeeder class like this $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class); i think that should solve your issue..although not a laravel expert

Comment: i tried but still same problem show , sir where i put "$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);" ,?? i am getting confuse

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the database directory is included in the composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ]
 }
```

All php files in that directory is scanned when "dumpautoload"-ing. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is coming in late, but it might help some future readers with similar problem.

Had this same issue and was able to solve it by doing composer dump-autoload in the root of my application

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Thank you @Mena for that observation, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey hi seeder should be like this

````
```class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 30)->create()->each(function($user) {
        $user->save();
       });
    }```
````

If you want to create a user that should be place in migration file not here. hope it will works for you